# BeautifulSoup (bs4), html5lib, HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1, column 11

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I need to copy the source code from a website onto an html file stored locally as parsing from the url directly does not capture all of the page elements. I am hoping to extract locational elements within a table in the source code to be used for geocoding. My program goes through several pages of search results, writing the source code from each to an html file stored locally. The address elements are only about a third of the material each page so it would be nice to get rid of the additional elements to reduce the file size.

To do this, I would like the program to open a blank html doc for writing, write the current page's source code to it, close the doc, reopen it for parsing (in 'r' mode now), open a new doc for writing, and use beautiful soup to capture all of the geocoding data form the first doc and write it to the new document. The program will then close the first doc and then reopen it in 'w' mode again.

This will be done in a loop so the first doc will always get overwritten with the current page's source code while the second doc will stay open and keep having just the geocoding data written to it until there are no more pages.

Everything with looping and navigating and writing the source code to file is working fine but i can't get the parsing part figured out. I tried experimenting in an interactive env with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

data = open(r"C:\GIS DataBase\web_resutls_raw_new_test.html",'r').read()
document = html5lib.parse(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(document))
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 228, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 289, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 219, in feed
    raise e
HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1, column 11
```

So I tried the following fix:

```
soup = HTMLParser.handle_starttag(BeautifulSoup(str(document)))
```

And alas:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 228, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 289, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 219, in feed
    raise e
HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1, column 11
```

I also tried with lxml, ertree and nothing seems to work. I cannot get the elements I need parsing from the url directly. I need to parse from the html file.

Comment: try passing `data` directly to `BeautifulSoup` as : `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')`

Comment: any chance you can include line 1 from your html file?

Comment: @Stack That did it. Thanks! Please add the answer and I'll check it.

Comment: @ShaunO Welcome ;)

Comment: Ok adding the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `data` directly to `BeautifulSoup` as :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
```